# Select2 Js not working in Swiper Js

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, swiper.js

Right now I am using Select2.js combined or put in Swiper.js and I also put that both in Bootstrap modal. But the problem is the Select2 Js is not working (**dropdown and filter textfiled aren't working**), Here the codes I have tried before:

Bootstrap:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="passModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Swiper JS

```
var swiperpass = new Swiper('.content-pass', {
            pagination: {
                el: '.numb-pagination',
                type: 'fraction',
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.form-next',
                prevEl: '.form-prev',
            },
            spaceBetween: 30
        });
```

Then, after looking for some solution I found a little solution (**dropdown is working**) by add `simulateTouch:false` in the code line:

```
var swiperpass = new Swiper('.content-pass', {
            pagination: {
                el: '.numb-pagination',
                type: 'fraction',
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.form-next',
                prevEl: '.form-prev',
            },
            spaceBetween: 30,
            simulateTouch:false
        });
```

But I still have a problem, **filter textfield is still not working**.

So, what should I do to make it work correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Here's the solution that I found :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="passModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It only need to remove the `tabindex="-1"`, then the problem solved.

Thank You